# Can't update to newer version of AWS-CDK

Tags: npm, aws-cdk

I have aws-cdk version 2.44.0.
I've got notified (after running `cdk diff`) that there is a newer version, 2.47.0, and I should run `npm install -g aws-cdk` to upgrade to this version. I ran this command successfully with `sudo` (since without it I get errors) and got the following output:

```
changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 2s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

but after check with `cdk --version` I found that the version is still 2.44.0.

additional information:

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Node.js v16.17
- npm version: 8.19.2

So, how to update aws-cdk successfuly?

Comment: What's the output of `which cdk`? Maybe you have run `sudo npm install -g aws-cdk` at some point before?

Comment: @gshpychka The output is `/usr/local/bin/cdk`, and yes, you right: I actually have run `sudo np install...` because `npm install` alone didn't work.

Comment: So you ran both `sudo npm install` and `npm install`? Please add all the commands you ran to the question.

Comment: No, only `sudo npm install`. I've edit the question accordingly to make it clear.

Comment: This is happening because you also installed `aws-cdk` using some other method alongside the latest version. Remove it first.

Comment: Can't believe it... Even after uninstall, the package is still there. I've run `sudo uninstall -g aws-cdk` and got 'removed 1 package, and audited 1 package in 271ms'. After this, I've run `cdk --version` and got `2.44.0 (build bf32cb1)`...

Comment: Right, refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Thank. It turned out that this old version was installed using older version of npm which installed it in `usr/local/bin`, while the newer version of npm installed the latest version of cdk in `usr/bin`. After locally uninstalled the older version and running again `which cdk` it finally recognized the newer version in `usr/bin`.

Comment: Great - add this as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that this old version was installed using older version of npm which installed it in `usr/local/bin`, while the newer version of npm installed the latest version of cdk in `usr/bin`. After locally uninstalled the older version and running again `which cdk` it finally recognized the newer version in `usr/bin`.

Comment: exactly my issue, thanks!